# Anaconda import Error

Tags: python-2.7, import, anaconda

I wrote my own module for Aanaconda and placed it into the correct site-package for Anaconda.

The issue I'm having is that Python says the module does not exist even though its saved in site-packages.

So how do I make /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages find my module?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your module isn't built correctly? Or you are using a different python than the one where you put your module?

Let's confirm the site-packages (and the python).  In your python interpreter do:

```
import site
site.getsitepackages()
```

Did that return `['/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/anaconda/lib/site-python']`? If it returned a different site-packages folder then put your module there. Perhaps you are using a different python (confirm with `which python`).

If that looked fine then I would check on your module. Are you sure you have the `__init__.py` defined? What error did you get?

Try creating a simple test module like:

```
simple_test/
|-- __init__.py
`-- simple.py
```

Where `simple.py` just has:

```
def print_hello():
    print("hello")
```

Now copy the whole of `simple_test` directory into the site-packages directory that we discovered above.  Now do, in the python interpreter, the following:

```
from simple_test.simple import print_hello
print_hello()
```

That should work and give a blueprint for how to do this setup.

FYI long term you should probably be building conda packages and installing them instead of doing this copying work.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot.